# Memory spaces of two activities in separate processes

Tags: android, process, multiprocessing

Do two `Activity`s running in separate processes have shared memory space? [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) in the Android documentation it says they have separate memory spaces.

But assume we have to `Activity`s: **FirstActivity** and **SecondActivity**. In the manifest, the `android:process` attribute is assigned to **SecondActivity** to make it run on a separate process. And assume **FirstActivity** has a public static field named **A**.

I start **SecondActivity** from **FirstActivity** using the `startActivity()` method, and I can access **FirstActivity.A** field and read its value which shows they shared the memory space. (but they're running in separate processes)

**EDIT** Here's the code:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application>

    <activity android:name=".FirstActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:process="another_process">

    </activity>

</application>
```

**FirstActivity**

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

    public static int A = 11111;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**SecondActivity**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gateway);

        Log.i("SecondActivity", "A = " + FirstActivity.A); // here
    }
}
```

What's happening? Is having separate memory spaces only for when two `Activity`s are in running from separate apps? Why the **A** variable is accessible from **SecondActivity**?

Comment: "What's happening?" -- most likely, you are misinterpreting what you are seeing. Please consider providing a [mcve], with the actual manifest and the actual activities and the actual test.

Comment: @CommonsWare Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's happening?

You are wondering why a constant is constant.

> Is having separate memory spaces only for when two Activitys are in running from separate apps

No. Your two activities are running in separate processes. However, the two processes have the same code, because it is the same app. And, `A`, being a constant, is effectively part of the code.

> Why the A variable is accessible from SecondActivity?

Because they both have the same code.